# sqlite3_bind_int64 returns error : bad parameter or other API misuse when called second time even after sqlite3_clear_bindings

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

Some context :
For a particular statement, I want to execute some repeated steps with different bindings.
The second call to `sqlite3_bind_parameter_index` returns Error.
I checked that until sqlite3_clear_bindings there was no error. I am new to using sqlite C interface APIs. Any help would be great.

My code is something like this :

```
sqlite3_stmt* pStmt;
while(...)
{
    sqlite3_reset(pStmt);
    sqlite3_clear_bindings(pStmt);
    i32 iS3Posn = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(pStmt, name);
    sqlite3_bind_int64(pStmt, iS3Posn, iValue);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. You should check the result of reset: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Please tag with the correct language.

Comment: You should check the results of *all* your function calls.